# Scale image from the middle using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scale

Is it possible to make a image scale from the middle with jQuery?
Right now it's going from top left.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#logo").animate({
        height: '+=100%',
        width: '+=100%'
    });

});
```

```css
#logoblock
{
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}
#logo
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logoblock">
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x700">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: no need for jquery. can you use css animations instead?

Comment: I need it in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

may b exactly not what you want

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#logo").animate({
    height: '+=100%',
    width: '+=100%',
    top: 0,
    left:0
});

});
```

css

```
#logoblock
{
position: relative;
width: 700px;
height: 700px;
margin: auto;
}
#logo
{
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
width: 0%;
height: 0%;
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/73h17m1t/

click `run` button after fiddle loaded and resize result frame to full size for best view.

Comment: No it's not from the middle, sorry

Comment: Agreed, it is not from the middle. But surprisingly, looks like from middle. Check in slow motion http://jsfiddle.net/wkeodutr/ :)

Answer (score 0):

You could start out with `transform scale(0)`;

adding a class that takes care about `transform:scale(1)` you can also `transition` (jquery `animate()` has some problems with transform properties )

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/73h17m1t/3/)